# How I can concatenate some css files via Brunch?

Tags: css, automation, brunch

I'm using some jquery libraries in project and CSS files for them. What is the best way to combine them into one CSS via Brunch?

Here is my app structure http://take.ms/jFkzD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already found reason of no compilation CSS files, its should be out of /assets folder